# Формирование разных переменных за каждый клик по кнопке

Tags: javascript, html5

Совсем туплю под вечер, но не клеится. Должно быть:

- клик 1: создание переменной `worker1`
- клик 2: создание переменной `worker2`
- клик 3: создание переменной `worker3`
- и т.д. по количеству кликов.

```js
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  let counter = 1;
  let worker = 'worker';
  for(let i=0; i <= counter; i++) {
      if(event.target) {
        worker += counter;
        
  }
    counter++;
  }
  console.log(worker) 
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
```

Comment: Ваш цикл никогда не закончится, так как Вы все время увеличиваете `counter`. Ничего не понял про переменные. И что это за условие `if(event.target)`?

Comment: За каждый цикл мне нужна новая переменная, а event.target - если был клик, то выполнить действие...

Comment: А если не было клика, как Вы тогда попали в его обработчик? Где Вам нужна "новая переменная"? Как Вы с этой пременной собираетесь работать? Кому из нас нужна помощь? И наконец: Вы партизан на допросе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let counter = 1;
   document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    let worker = 'worker' + counter;
    console.log(worker);
    counter++;
})
```

```html
<button id="button">Button</button>
```